# How to save inherited class using TemplateHibernate in Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have a problem when trying to save an inherited object using TemplateHibernate:
Let's say that I have two classes as following:
  Contact <--------- EntrepriseContact
and here is the contact.hbm.xml

```
   <joined-subclass name="Entreprise" table="Entreprise">
            <key column="ID_ENTREPRISE"  />
            <property name="numSiret">
                <column name="NUM_SIRET" />
            </property>
        </joined-subclass>
```

When I create a Entreprise object and save it using Hibernate, it works

```
try
        {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory =
                new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

       ........................................

            session.saveOrUpdate(entreprise);
            tx.commit();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

But when I tried to use HibernateTemplate, I got the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: domain.Contact; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: domain.Contact
```

How can I fix this problem?

Note that when I tried with Contact, I worked in both situations, but with Entreprise, it didn't work :(

Comment: You did not provide hibernateTemplate code here. Please post that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Spring Source Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate), to check how to use hibernateTemplate.